# Как реализовать загрузчик ресурса из веба в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, mono

У меня стоит две задачи:

1. Я хочу загружаться текстовый файл из веба, но я не понимаю как написать класс, у которого будет статический метод, который принимает url и в итоге возвращает скаченный контент. А именно мне не понятно как это провернуть с IEnumerator, учитвая, что он ни чего не возвращает наружу при выполнение.
2. Я хотел бы производить загрузку во время инициализации игры. Тестовый файл будет содержать конфиги для всего (скороть движение игрока и т.д.). И на сколько я понимаю, выполнение IEnumerator - это не блокирующая операция. Как реализовать?

Comment: Что с енумератором, что без него - задачи полностью идентичны. Не думайте о енумераторе, представьте что это обычный геттер, или функция возвращающая значение. У Вас есть хоть какие нибудь наработки?

Comment: @test123 наработок нет, только пример из документации https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html, который собственно и использует IEnumerator. Мои познания как в платформе Mono, так и в языке C# скудноваты. Я понимаю как если бы я писал на JavaScript (с промисами или коллбеками). Выполнил бы запрос, дождался бы ответа и только потом начал инициализацию игры.

Answer (score 1):

Как так. Сам не проверял, но вроде работать должно. Где action- функцию в которую передается текст, а дальше по желанию.

```
public stati class Load {
    public static void LoadFile(MonoBehevior m, string url, Action<string> action) {
        m.StartCoroutine(LoadCoroutine(url, action));
    }
    private static IEnumerator LoadCoroutine(string u, Action<string> a) {
        using(WWW url=new WWW(u)) {
            yield return url;
            if(url.error!=null&&url.error!="") {
                a(url.text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```